# Combining sql queries together

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to simplify my current query code. Is there a simpler way of combining both queries into one?

Here is what I have tried so far. Although it seems really messy and clunky. This query requests all the clients

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY name DESC
```

I then have another request inside to find if the client has a booking

```
SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE client_id=$client_id AND done=0
```

Done represents if the job is completed, and there can only be 1 uncompleted job per client at a time.

Explanation:

The code needs to show all the clients and if the client has a booking and if the other database returns a result, the booking button won't appear, if no results (i.e, all previous bookings for that client are 1) a book button appears.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: use mysql join for combining query

Comment: I want to have SELECT * FROM clients, bookings ORDER BY name DESC IF bookings.done=0 But to always list the clients. If done is equal to 0, per client, there needs to be an if($done=0){show button}else{no button}

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select c.*, coalesce(b.done, 1) completed
from clients c
left join bookings b on b.client_id = c.client_id and b.done = 0
```

This attempts to find a uncompleted row in `booking` for each client. Column `completed` in the resultset contains `0` if the client has an uncompleted row, else `1`.

Comment: Okay, so if I just $row["completed"] it will tell me per client if its 0 or 1

Comment: @Jackbeeby: yes, exactly.

Comment: How would I then go about attaching a third table to this? it's a clients table, were clients.client_id is in respect of addresses.client_id. I tried adding d.* and clients d and WHERE c.client_id=d.client_id"

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a flag, then you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM bookings b
                WHERE ON c.client_id = b.client_id AND b.done = 0
               )
       ) as has_booking
FROM clients c ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT clients.*, bookings.done
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN bookings ON bookings.client_id = clients.client_id
AND b.done = 0
```

With the above result, you can add a condition in your view

```
if(done == 0){
     show button code
}
```